# How to change empty datatable message into an image?

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, datatables

I use these code to customize my datatable.

```
    "language": {
        "lengthMenu": "Menampilkan  _MENU_  Baris",
        "zeroRecords": "Data Tidak Tersedia",
        "info": "Menampilkan Halaman _PAGE_ Dari _PAGES_",
        "infoEmpty": "Data Tidak Tersedia",
        "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)",
        "oPaginate": {
        "sNext" : "Selanjutnya",
        "sPrevious" : "Sebelumnya",
    },
```

but they just change the language of my datatable menu.
and my question is how to change a ZeroRecords message into an image? I want my datatable show an image when empty.
Please somebody help me.
thank's anyway

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206419/view-pictures-or-images-inside-jquery-datatable

Comment: i found a solution that almost fix my issue "initComplete": function(settings, json) {

        $('.dataTables_empty').html('<img src="{{asset(vendor/notfound.png)}}"/>');
        
    }, but idk how the image still doesn't show

Comment: Check path of image

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this simple step.
change: this line

```
"zeroRecords": "Data Tidak Tersedia",
```

To:

```
"zeroRecords": "<img src='https://your-url-image'>",
```